# Removed array grouped key

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

Is it possible to remove the key after data is grouped? Now I'm working with the csv file import function. I have two rows of data with the same student but different books because I want to group the books based on the student ID.

Code

```
foreach ($book as $item) {
    $item['books'] = [
        'number' => $item['number'],
        'description' => $item['description'],
    ];

    if (!isset($group_by[$item['student_id']])) {
        $group_by[$item['student_id']] = array(
            'student_id' => $item['student_id'],
            'name' => $item['name'],
        );
    }

    $group_by[$item['student_id']]['books'][] = $item['books'];
}
```

This is my grouping function, it worked perfectly as expected but the data structure is not matched to my system

Result is here

```
array:1 [
  "ST001" => array:9 [
    "student_id" => "ST001"
    "name" => "joe"
    "books" => array:2 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "number" => "1"
        "description" => "The magic"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "number" => "2"
        "description" => "Forest in norway"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Expect result

```
array:9 [
    "student_id" => "ST001"
    "name" => "joe"
    "books" => array:2 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "number" => "1"
        "description" => "The magic"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "number" => "2"
        "description" => "Forest in norway"
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

I have no idea how to remove the `St001` array. I did tried this `$group_by[] = array(` but the `books` data will be break out of data structure.

Comment: If iundesrstand your question i think your code is correct. Because if you have for example ST002 you can collect both data into one array like $group_by['ST001 ']=> array with data  $group_by['ST002 ']=> array with data.

Comment: Hm, `$group_by[$item['student_id']] ` you set it here, and you don't want it anymore?

Comment: @Sfili_81 Yes......the code is working as expected. I'm just looking for a way to remove that key in order to match to my system.

Comment: @kerbholz Correct

Comment: If you remove it, what appen if you have more than one student_id?

Comment: This question is Unclear/Ill-considered.  If you remove the first layer, you'll get data collisions. If you just want reindexing l, use `array_values()` -- but that is not what your question is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the inner array to another array.

```
$array = $array['ST001'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help out here

```
foreach($book as $item)
{
$item['books'] = ['number' => $item['number'], 'description' => $item['description'], ];
if (!isset($group_by[$item['student_id']]))
    {
    $group_by[$item['student_id']] = array(
        'student_id' => $item['student_id'],
        'name' => $item['name'],
    );
    }

$group_by[$item['student_id']]['books'][] = $item['books'];
}

// remove key and get only value as you want

print_r(array_values($group_by));
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case you could use reset():

```
$array = reset($array);
```

*reset() rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and returns the value of the first array element.*

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

Comment: Why downvote? This works even when they don't know the student ID.